# How to detect if an android device really needs read permission to access the obb in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are currently developing a game with Unity3d, and at the moment, the Android version is around 250MB, so we need to use an OBB expansion file to be able to publish it in the Play Store.

We have already integrated the script in Unity3d that requests read permission at run time to mount the OBB. We would like to request this permission ONLY if the device really needs it.

We have done some tests with devices with Android 7 and 8 in which we have been able to access the OBB correctly without requesting permission.

The Android Developers documentation (https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files) says the following: "For Android (version 6 and later), external storage permission needs to be requested at runtime, but some implementations of Android do not require permission to read OBB files."

There is also an example in Java of how to detect the need for permission, but we would not know how to perform this check in Unity. Does anyone know any method?

Thanks in advance.